# Translate the menu bar component of PrimeNG using TypeScript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, primeng

I want to translate primeNG menu bar component. But I don't know how to handle the translation inside of .ts file. I want to get translate data from the .json file.

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { SocialAuthService, SocialUser } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { MenuItem, MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  display: boolean = true;
  socialUser: SocialUser = new SocialUser();
  items: MenuItem[] = [];

  constructor(private socialAuthService: SocialAuthService
    , private toast: MessageService, private translateService: TranslateService
    ) {
      this.items.map(item => item.label = this.translateService.instant(item.label));
     }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe(_ => {
      this.socialUser = _;
    });

    

    this.items = [
      { label: 'menu.pManagement', icon: 'pi pi-chart-line'},
      { label: 'menu.iList', icon: 'pi pi-wallet', routerLink: 'outsourcing' },
      { label: 'menu.iAnalysis, icon: 'pi pi-clock'}
    ];
  }

  addToast() {
    this.toast.add({
      severity: 'success',
      summary: 'Success',
      detail: ''
    });
  }

}
```

Upper you can see my menu bar items. I want to change the label name when I change the language from the language change dropdown.

here is the en.json file

```
{
    
"menu" : {
        "pManagement" : "Project Management",
        "iList" : "Item list",
        "iAnalysis" : "Item analysis"
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look at Transloco.

Comment: Thank you I will see! @frosty